# Unable to specify folder in log4net when logging from window service

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, windows-services, log4net, aspnetboilerplate

I am running a .NET Core 3.1 application as a Windows service and have added log4net logging into it. The issue I'm encountering is that it logs to the "C:/Windows/System32/Logs" folder instead of the directory where the .exe file is located. I understand that the execution path differs for Windows services, leading to logs being saved in a different location. However, is there a method to modify the folder so that it logs to the same directory as the .exe file? For all the other web applications in the solution, it logs to the same published folder.

Here is the log4net config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Logs/Logs.txt" />
    <encoding value="utf-8" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="50MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5level %date [%-5.5thread] %-40.40logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    <level value="INFO" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

and here is the configuration in startup.cs file:

```
 public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {

     var configFilepath = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "log4net.config");
     return services.AddAbp<EMMSubscriberModule>(
         options => options.IocManager.IocContainer.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(
             f => f.UseAbpLog4Net().WithConfig(configFilepath)
         )
     );
 }
```

and the Program.cs file

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     var host = BuildWebHost(args);

     if (Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--debug"))
     {
         host.Run();
     }
     else
     {
         host.RunAsService();
     }
 }

 public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
 {
     ...

     return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
         .UseStartup<Startup>()
         .UseContentRoot(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
         .Build();
 }
```

Comment: Sorry Jason, I was stuck in another thing so didn't get a chance to look into this. Will do it and reply tou back.

Comment: Could you kindly check the updated answer ? If you need further help, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the current directory to the one where your assemblies are being found.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Environment.CurrentDirectory = AppContext.BaseDirectory;

    var host = BuildWebHost(args);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Here we go, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE

Using below code and it works properly in my side.

[image]

[image]

```
var logRepository = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
var appBasePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
GlobalContext.Properties["LogDir"] = Path.Combine(appBasePath, "Logs");
XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepository, new FileInfo(Path.Combine(appBasePath, "log4net.config")));

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

**PREVIOUS**

I know you're using ABP, but the method should be the same, we need to use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory to set the working path to run so that the log4net log location is valid.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        string logDir = Path.Combine(baseDir, "Logs");
        string logPath = Path.Combine(logDir, "Logs.txt");

        if (!Directory.Exists(logDir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(logDir);
        }

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("logPath", logPath);

        WebApplicationOptions options = new()
        {
            ContentRootPath = baseDir,
            Args = args,
            WebRootPath = Path.Combine(baseDir, "wwwroot")
        };

        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(options);
        ...
        app.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Jason, I've updated my original question and added the Program.cs file. I am already setting ConentRootPath to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory but that didn't help. It's still logging in C://Windows/System32/Logs directory.

Comment: Actually when I use UseAbpLog4Net(), it sets the LogRepositoy. In the other project I configured log4net without ABP and there I was able to create the instance of LogRepository. ABP provides less flexibility. So that's why I am unable to specify a folder.

Comment: Hi @Ask I'm testing a template project for asp.net core, and I'm glad you could share this information with me.